# Deep-copy does not generate a copy of an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, deep-copy

I am trying to rotate and translate a picture using OpenCV. The picture is stored in an object "original".  I tried various ways to create a deepcopy of that original because I want 3 different pictures: A translated one, a rotated one, and one translated and then rotated. But if I start my code I only get the same picture first rotated, then additionally translated and lastly once again translated and rotated.

I tried to read the original image in new objects which did not change the outcome. Surprisingly the original image can still be displayed using pyplot. I really don't get what is the problem here.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import cv2


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def rotate(image, angle):

    rows,cols = image.shape[:2]
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),angle,1)
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (cols, rows))

def translate(image, x, y):

    rows,cols = image.shape[:2]

    M = np.float32([[1,0,x],[0,1,y]])
    return cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))

from copy import deepcopy
original = cv2.imread("Darth.jpg")
original2 = deepcopy(original)
original3 = deepcopy(original)

print(original.shape)
img = rotate(original, 15)
cv2.imwrite("Darth1.jpg", img)



img_trans= translate(original2, 20, 20)
cv2.imwrite("Darth2.jpg", img_trans)



img_trans_rot= rotate(translate(original3, 20, 20), 30)
cv2.imwrite("Darth3.jpg", img_trans_rot)



fig=plt.figure(figsize=(18, 16), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.subplot(1,4,1)
plt.imshow(original)
plt.subplot(1,4,2)
plt.imshow(img)

plt.subplot(1,4,3)
plt.imshow(img_trans)

plt.subplot(1,4,4)
plt.imshow(img_trans_rot)
```

Output of the script:

[image: Output of the script]

Comment: It's just a small typo: `img` in `return cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))` should be `image`. Fix it and you will get your expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just didn't find it and then overlooked it again and again.